# Parse Error from timestamp packed telematic elements

Tags: thingsboard

A dataconverter creates the next json result from a datalogger.

```
{
"deviceName": "1185",
"deviceType": "campbell_scientific",
"groupName": "campbell_scientific",
"telemetry": [{
    "ts": 1582109460,
    "values": {
        "Voltage_Pb": 12.18,
        "Distancia": 14,
        "Level": 200,
        "Clppm": 41,
        "Caudal": 44,
        "Volumen": 77,
        "Caudal_2": 99,
        "Volumen_2": 6,
        "Caudal_3": 40,
        "Volumen_3": 40,
        "Caudal_4": 4,
        "Volumen_4": 440
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1582109520,
    "values": {
        "Voltage_Pb": 12.18,
        "Distancia": 44,
        "Level": 44,
        "Clppm": 25,
        "Caudal": 255,
        "Volumen": 740,
        "Caudal_2": 7420,
        "Volumen_2": 720,
        "Caudal_3": 2720,
        "Volumen_3": 770,
        "Caudal_4": 770,
        "Volumen_4": 550
    }
}]
```

}

But looks like like something is wrong. Reading that class to guess what could be, but looks like I miss something that I can't find in the poor documentation. I get the following error, don't know why.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Can't parse value: {"Voltage_Pb":12,"Distancia":14,"Level":200,"Clppm":41,"Caudal":44,"Volumen":77,"Caudal_2":99,"Volumen_2":6,"Caudal_3":40,"Volumen_3":40,"Caudal_4":4,"Volumen_4":440}
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.parseProtoValues(JsonConverter.java:225)
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.parseWithoutTs(JsonConverter.java:183)
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.parseObject(JsonConverter.java:176)
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.parseObject(JsonConverter.java:112)
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.lambda$convertToTelemetry$0(JsonConverter.java:98)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.convertToTelemetry(JsonConverter.java:96)
at org.thingsboard.server.common.adaptor.JsonConverter.convertToTelemetryProto(JsonConverter.java:88)
at org.thingsboard.integration.api.converter.AbstractUplinkDataConverter.parseTelemetry(AbstractUplinkDataConverter.java:150)
at org.thingsboard.integration.api.converter.AbstractUplinkDataConverter.parseUplinkData(AbstractUplinkDataConverter.java:115)
at org.thingsboard.integration.api.converter.AbstractUplinkDataConverter.convertUplink(AbstractUplinkDataConverter.java:75)
at org.thingsboard.integration.api.AbstractIntegration.convertToUplinkDataList(AbstractIntegration.java:226)
at org.thingsboard.integration.http.basic.BasicHttpIntegration.processUplinkData(BasicHttpIntegration.java:200)
at org.thingsboard.integration.http.basic.BasicHttpIntegration.doProcess(BasicHttpIntegration.java:87)
at org.thingsboard.integration.http.AbstractHttpIntegration.process(AbstractHttpIntegration.java:54)
at org.thingsboard.integration.http.AbstractHttpIntegration.process(AbstractHttpIntegration.java:42)
at org.thingsboard.server.controller.LocalIntegrationControllerApi.process(LocalIntegrationControllerApi.java:58)
at org.thingsboard.integration.http.controller.http.HttpIntegrationController.lambda$processRequest$1(HttpIntegrationController.java:84)
at org.thingsboard.common.util.DonAsynchron$1.onSuccess(DonAsynchron.java:53)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1135)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Any suggestion?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the structure:

change your converter to send data like this :

[{
    "ts": 1582109460,
    "values": {
        "Voltage_Pb": 12,
        "Distancia": 14,
        "Level": 200,
        "Clppm": 41,
        "Caudal": 44,
        "Volumen": 77,
        "Caudal_2": 99,
        "Volumen_2": 6,
        "Caudal_3": 40,
        "Volumen_3": 40,
        "Caudal_4": 4,
        "Volumen_4": 440
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1582109520,
    "values": {
        "Voltage_Pb": 12,
        "Distancia": 44,
        "Level": 44,
        "Clppm": 25,
        "Caudal": 255,
        "Volumen": 740,
        "Caudal_2": 7420,
        "Volumen_2": 720,
        "Caudal_3": 2720,
        "Volumen_3": 770,
        "Caudal_4": 770,
        "Volumen_4": 550
    }
}]